# webdav - Can't upload file from Explorer to NGINX Webdav server

Tags: linux, networking, windows-explorer, nginx, webdav

### Situation

I've setup an NGINX based Webdav server with SSL enabled. When I tried to connect to the server from Windows Explorer, everything works fine until I uploaded a file.
Windows Explorer said *The destination already has a file named "[filename]"*, and if click *Replace*, Windows prompted *Can't read from the source file or disk*.

After the failure, I refreshed the Windows Explorer and found that a new file with exact same [filename] has been created on Webdav server and it was 0kb (no data).
I've tried connecting with WinSCP and Cyberduck and everything works fine, no issue with upload/download.

### Little Workaround

I've checked my NGINX configuration and can't find problem with it. And here's my NGINX configuration.

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
load_module /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location / {
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

webdav.conf

```
server {
    listen 6999 ssl http2;
    server_name my.domain;

    ssl_certificate /path/to/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /path/to/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5";
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;

    client_header_timeout 120s;
    client_body_timeout 120s;
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location / {

        # Windows Explorer Workaround
        #if (-d $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ break; }
        #if ($request_method = MKCOL) { rewrite ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ break; }

        root /path/to/webdav/folder;
        dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
        dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS LOCK UNLOCK;

        dav_access user:rw group:rw all:rw;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        create_full_put_path on;
        client_body_temp_path /srv/client-temp;
        autoindex on;

        auth_basic on;
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/users.list;

        allow all;
    }
}
```

I did some google-ing and found this [article](https://medium.com/@cetteup/cant-create-or-delete-directories-on-an-nginx-webdav-server-here-s-how-to-fix-that-76ffedcb5b51). However it did't help.
Also, I tried setting my webdav folder permission to 777 and changed owner to nginx, didn't help.

I checked NGINX access log and found this.

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:06 +0800] "PUT /config HTTP/2.0" 201 0 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:06 +0800] "LOCK /config HTTP/2.0" 405 157 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:06 +0800] "PROPFIND /config HTTP/2.0" 207 463 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:07 +0800] "PROPFIND /config HTTP/2.0" 207 463 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:07 +0800] "PROPFIND /config HTTP/2.0" 207 463 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:07 +0800] "PROPFIND /Thumbs.db HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:20:07 +0800] "PROPFIND /Documents/somefile HTTP/2.0" 207 511 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /macOS%20Files HTTP/2.0" 207 448 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /Documents/somefile HTTP/2.0" 207 511 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /config HTTP/2.0" 207 463 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /config%20(2) HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND / HTTP/2.0" 207 424 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "LOCK /config HTTP/2.0" 405 157 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /config HTTP/2.0" 207 463 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "LOCK /config HTTP/2.0" 405 157 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "PROPFIND /config HTTP/2.0" 207 463 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:21:33 +0800] "LOCK /config HTTP/2.0" 405 157 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:22:52 +0800] "PROPFIND /macOS%20Files HTTP/2.0" 207 448 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:22:52 +0800] "PROPFIND /desktop.ini HTTP/2.0" 404 153 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:22:52 +0800] "PROPFIND / HTTP/2.0" 207 424 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:22:52 +0800] "PROPFIND / HTTP/2.0" 207 2231 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:29:09 +0800] "PROPFIND /macOS%20Files HTTP/2.0" 207 448 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - username [29/Sep/2019:15:30:38 +0800] "PROPFIND /macOS%20Files HTTP/2.0" 207 448 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/10.0.18362" "-"
```

No log output in NGINX error log.

Huge thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The [nginx webdav module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_dav_module.html) only supports PUT, DELETE, MKCOL, COPY, and MOVE.

The [dav_ext module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module) adds support for PROPFIND, OPTIONS, LOCK and UNLOCK.

Unfortunately, Windows attempts to create files using a PUT of a zero-size file, followed by a PROPPATCH to copy the contents.  I have not had success using Nginx to support WebDAV on Windows.  I eventually resorted to using Apache with the `dav` and `dav_fs` modules.

Answer (score -1):

Try use config from there http://netlab.dhis.org/wiki/ru:software:nginx:webdav
It is work for me.